# How to manage multiple states in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Screen component called "EditProfile" which contains three forms:

> 1. The UserInformationForm, which contains several information of the user as states.
> 2. The ChangePasswordForm, which contains the password and repeat password of the user as states
> 3. The ChangeAvatarForm, which contains the avatar uri as state.

All these components have a common parent, the screen EditProfile, as I said. In this screen I have the logic to upload all the information to a DB.

I need to access each child information, so imagine that I have all the forms states in the parent. I think that having multiple states (more than 20) in the parent is insane and can affect performance... So I have thought to wrap each child with the hook useImperativeHandle, just to retrieve all this data without having to save all the states in the parent and avoid unnecesary re-renders... I don't know if this is a good practice as in the documentation says to avoid this type of behaviour and use the common data flow...

Is it normal to have all those states in the parent? Can I use the useImperativeHandle hook in this situation? Any patterns?

Thank you.

### UPDATE

I mean, something like this:

ChangeAvatarForm.js

```
const ChangeAvatarForm = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getAvatar: () => avatar,
  }));

  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(props.avatar);
  ...
```

EditProfile.js (The parent screen which have all the forms)

```
export default function EditProfile(props) {
  const { information } = props; // Current user information

  // References to each form
  const avatarFormRef = useRef(null);
  const userInformationFormRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordFormRef = useRef(null);


  const submitChanges = () => {
     // Get the new avatar
     const newAvatar = avatarFormRef.current.getAvatar();

     ...
  }
```

...

Comment: Are you opening to learning [xstate](https://xstate.js.org/)? It can manage your state for related information, and even handle your api calls. It is one solution for a cleaner state setup. If you are interested, I'll prepare a simple Sandbox for you!

Comment: I was under the impression that state is usually handled (if not in a 'store') as an object on the main APP. that sends props to all children. are you using state in parent components below the main APP? I'm new to react myself - so I'm not sure why that would be better than having a main 'state storage area'?

Comment: @altruios I am not using redux. Updating states in the parent causes child re-renders, so it is better to save states in each child than in a common parent, just to re-render only the necessary parts. Also, as more complex are my childs, more states I will have in the parent, making it harder to read.

Comment: but isn't the point of react to use state to avoid re-rendering to the dom? with that I thought only things with changed props get re-rendered, not the object holding state?